# Trouble Achieving Full Container Width in Vuetify App Layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I just want to get started and setup a simple app layout with Vuetify.

Code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <!-- Header -->
      <v-app-bar app color="primary">
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-toolbar-title>My Vuetify App</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn text>Home</v-btn>
        <v-btn text>About</v-btn>
        <v-btn text>Contact</v-btn>
      </v-app-bar>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <v-main>
        <v-container fluid>
          Hello World!
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

My issue is that the main content will not take up the full width, and I also want the text/content to be aligned to the left and to have the background color from the default theme. How can I achieve this?

Image:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the DOM inspector and check the CSS being applied.  You may have some other code/styling affecting the look, which we can't tell from the given code/screenshot.  As it is now, your code [does not reproduce the issue](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9UsFOwzAM/RUvZ9IetguoVJq47LIrHCiHNPWkSGkSZW5Fhfh3nKoaDRs72Xl+L46f8/4lzlGX+xCKcUDxJCrCPlhFWDcOoBqlCmFO54P2jpRxGBeIwY2UcEDVYQQpf+FZKFsVgSNob318bkSIpldxasSFuKZKp0ZpuEddlTfATELe21QlQxbr4wSvA5I5TcCjJHVez6TnoDRPkFhLmpVbckD4SfXB95hIDPzD2Ld+oPuUl+SYviKtBmQsM/PIBkOSoaM/lvZcyvtcFgInO5iu5lVY6+HNR9tt5i43Vsbo6qZr0vI4zqty9R3E94PYFtviUaS4K3bi4wdg768U)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. In the main.js file, there was this line at the top: import './assets/main.css'. After I deleted it, everything works as expected.